# Show login JS popup for auth required actions

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, kohana

I want to show a login popup, kind of overlay handled by JS when user clicks on any button/link which requires user to be logged in.
For Eg: If user tries to comment without signing in, on click of post I have to show this popup.

This is not ajax call where I can just reveal the popup based on the server response.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe by checking the status code or something like that?

The challenge is, when user is logged in the specific action takes user to another page, but when user is not logged in I want to suppress this and instead show login popup in same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful, even in chrome you can directly edit the javascript just by right clicking on the page > inspect element > resources > javascript, and typing your changes in, bypassing your check. Just to keep in mind that you use it only to increase the user experience, but make sure your php or whichever server side script checks for a valid session.

So assuming you are taking care of that, if you add a class to your buttons/links like so:

```
<a href="go_to_post.php" class="requires_login">Post Comment</a>
<form><input type="submit" class="requires_login" value="Post Comment" /></form>
```

you could for instance use javascript or jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var valid_session='<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['id']) ? 'true':'false'); ?>';
  $('.requires_login').on('click',function(event){
    if (valid_session=='false'){
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('open popup instead');
      //for instancce, $('#my_popup').show(); if you have:
      //<div id="my_popup">You must be logged in first!</div>
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to redirect on the page that requires a login, you can do that with `$this->response->redirect('auth/login');`

If you really insist on a js popup you either have to use AJAX or you could write the following in your view:

```
<script language="javascript">
var loggedIn = <?= Auth::instance()->logged_in() ? "true" : "false" ?>
</script>
```

You would have to check on each action if the user is logged in before redirecting.
Also a problem with this approach is that it does not handle session timeouts.